# Windows CMD command for accessing usb?

Tags: cmd

I have tried googling it but couldn't find it. I know the command for it is cd /media for linux but have no idea what it is for Windows.I also tried the dir command but couldn't find anything related to media or usb.

Comment: Do you want to find the Drive letter of your connected USB drive ?

Comment: I just want to go to the directory of it to access it since I am trying to delete some things off of it. Just like how you would type "cd /media" then "cd /name of usb" in Linux.

Comment: So you must know the drive letter of your USB like f:\ or j:\

Comment: Windows does not implement the "Everything is a file"-philosophy that is one of UNIX's defining aspects (inherited by Linux), so you cannot access USB devices (or other system objects) via the filesystem.

Comment: Ohhhh, that makes a lot more sense! Now how do I actually go about finding and doing all this stuff, drive letter?

Comment: I came here looking for something equivalent to the linux command lsusb which shows the USB devices connected and information about them.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can access the USB drive by its drive letter. To know the drive letter you can run this command:

```
C:\>wmic logicaldisk where drivetype=2 get deviceid, volumename, description
```

From here you will get the drive letter (Device ID) of your USB drive.

For example if its F: then run the following command in command prompt to see its contents:

```
C:\> F:

F:\> dir
```

Comment: Thanks, that's really simple and all I needed to know.

Answer (score 0):

firstly you have to change the drive, which is allocated to your usb.

follow these step to access your pendrive using CMD.
1- type drivename follow by the colon just like k:
2- type dir it will show all the files and directory in your usb
3- now you can access any file or directory of your usb.

Answer (score 0):

Try this batch :

```
@echo off
Title List of connected external devices by Hackoo
Mode con cols=100 lines=20 & Color 9E
wmic LOGICALDISK where driveType=2 get deviceID > wmic.txt
for /f "skip=1" %%b IN ('type wmic.txt') DO (echo %%b & pause & Dir %%b)
Del wmic.txt
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be unrelated, but I found this thread while trying to reset my user data, and I found that you can go to the file in file explorer and drag it into the console window and it will create the path. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7Iah.png)[Example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xaz5y.png)